# Proof a set cannot contain its own powerset - Russell's Paradox

Tags: set-theory

Using naive set theory and not using the cardinal number of a power set, how can you prove a set cannot contain its own power set?
Is this connected to Russell's Paradox?

Comment: Contain as an element or contain as a subset?

Comment: Do you mean something like Cantor's theorem?

Comment: Contain as a subset

Comment: Nightgap, yes, but not using the cardinal number of the power set

Comment: The proof of Cantor's theorem doesn't need cardinal numbers (like Mr. Chip demonstrated, or see wikipedia alternatively). It just makes an assertion about them.

Comment: Exactly what does "using naive set theory" mean here? Naive set theory" has several different meanings, some of which would make this question very non0interesting.

Comment: I think we should reopen this question or mark it as protected for historical reasons. I got stuck on the second exercise in Jech (which resembles this question) and couldn't see how to do it without invoking regularity (which is not introduced until later in the book).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is connected to Russell's paradox.

Given a set $S$, we can consider the "Russell set" *built from* $S$ - this is just $$\mathcal{R}_S=\{a\in S: a\not\in a\}.$$ The important thing to note is that *this isn't necessarily paradoxical*, since there is in general no reason to believe $\mathcal{R}_S\in S$. However, certain kinds of $S$ *do* yield paradoxes. The famous one is when we take $S$ to be the "set of all sets." Then:

- $\mathcal{R}_S\in S$, since $S$ contains all sets.
- If $\mathcal{R}_S\not\in\mathcal{R}_S$, then $\mathcal{R}_S$ is an element of $S$ not containing itself, so $\mathcal{R}_S\in \mathcal{R}_S$.
- If $\mathcal{R}_S\in\mathcal{R}_S$, then $\mathcal{R}_S$ must not contain itself since the only elements of $\mathcal{R}_S$ are sets which don't contain themselves; that is, $\mathcal{R}_S\not\in\mathcal{R}_S$.
- So we have a contradiction.

---

It turns out this line of reasoning *also* works if $S$ is just some set containing its own powerset! HINT:

- $\mathcal{R}_S\subseteq S$, always (why?).
- So $\mathcal{R}_S\in S$ in this particular case (what assumption about $S$ are we using here?).
- From that, we can just run the Russell argument above (do you see how?).

Comment: Do you perhaps want $s \notin s$ in your first indented line?

Comment: @Mr.Chip Derp, fixed!

Answer (score 1):

Assume $S$ contains all its subsets as elements. Some of those (e.g. $S$ itself) contain themselves (as elements), some (such as the empty set) do not.

Let $X \subseteq S$, $X\in S$ be the set of those subsets of $S$ that do not contain themselves. Does it contain itself? (If it does, then it doesn't and the other way round.) This contradiction concludes the proof.