# Prove that for all $x$, $x \ne P(x)$, where $P(x)$ is the power set of $x$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Prove that for all $x$, $x \ne P(x)$, where $P(x)$ is the power set of $x$

My idea to solve this: 
Let's suppose that there exists a set which is in the same time its own power set. Then, by the axiom of extentionality: $x \in P(x) \iff x \in x $. 
We know from definition of the power set that $x \in P(x) $, which entails that $x \in x$, which is a contradiction (Russel). 
Is it a correct way to solve this problem? If so, is it possible to solve this without using the axiom of regularity?

Comment: I don't get the reference to Russel (it's in fact a contradiction to regularity) but otherwise this seems fine. I'll add an answer showing how to do it without regularity as well.

Comment: You don't need extensionality to conclude $x\in P(x)\iff x\in x$ from the assumption that $x=P(x)$. If $a=b$, then the elements of $a$ are exactly the elements of $b$ - this is just by the basic rules of logic. Extensionality goes the *other* way, and says that if we know that the elements of $a$ are exactly the elements of $b$ then we know that $a=b$.

Comment: I saw pretty much the same thing yesterday: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2536910

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x\in x$ is not necessarily a contradiction; if we don't assume the Axiom of Regularity, it is consistent with the rest of ZFC that there may exist sets that contain themselves.

However, if we have the Axiom of Separation, $X=\mathcal P(X)$ leads to a Russell-like contradiction by considering 
$$ Y = \{ a \in X \mid a \notin a \} $$
Since $Y\subseteq X$ by construction, we have $Y\in\mathcal P(X)=X$, and therefore $Y\in Y$ if and only if $Y\notin Y$ -- a contradiction.

Comment: I don't understand how you concluded that $Y \in Y \iff Y \notin Y$. Could you explain it a little bit more deeply?

Comment: @Aemilius: $Y$ has, by definition, the property that $a\in Y\leftrightarrow a\notin a$ for every $a\in X$. Since we have just argued that $Y\in X$, $Y$ itself is such a possible $a$, and setting $a$ to $Y$ produces $Y\in Y\leftrightarrow Y\notin Y$.

Answer (score 1):

*Theorem (Cantor).* For every set $x$ we have that $\mathrm{card}(x) < \mathrm{card}(\mathcal{P}(x))$.

*Proof.* Suppose that $x$ is such that there is a surjection $f \colon x \to \mathcal{P}(x)$. Define $y \subseteq x$ by
$$
y := \{ z \in x \mid z \not \in f(z) \}.
$$
Now, since $f$ is surjective, there is some $z \in x$ such that $f(z) = y$. But this implies that
$$
z \in y \iff z \not \in f(z) \iff z \not \in y.
$$
Contradiction! Q.E.D.

*Corollary.* For all $x \colon x \not = \mathcal{P}(x)$.